# Adding drop shadow to UIWebView and UITextView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad, shadow

I have a UITextView and a WebView side by side and I would like to add a drop shadow to both. This is an iPad app, so they rotate, thus an ImageView under them probably would not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UIViews have CALayers, that have some built-in shadow support.  Try these properties out:

```
view.layer.shadowColor
view.layer.shadowOffset
view.layer.shadowOpacity
view.layer.shadowRadius
```

That may get you what you need pretty quickly.  You might need to #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> to get the compiler to understand what's going on.

Comment: Was able to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Care to post your solution? The accepted answer doesn't seem to work for me as written.

Answer (score 7):

the solution would be like

```
[myTextBox.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[myTextBox.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];
[myTextBox.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[myTextBox.layer setShadowRadius:0.3];
```

but this just works for OS 3.2 and up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is swift version:

```
func applyDropShadow() {
    textView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    textView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3)
    textView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    textView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0
    textView.clipsToBounds = false

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this - without clipsToBounds the shadow wasn't appearing for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a view that sits behind the text field, and apply the shadow effects to that. This way the shadow does not move with the content.